# Get Sub-string From URL in FTL

Tags: freemarker

I have the below URL string say /level1/level2/level3/_________________

Now I need to get the sub-string till level 3. i.e. /level1/level2/level3 . How can I achieve it?

Thanks,

Comment: `url?replace(horribleRegularExpressionHere, '$1', 'r')` is a possible candidate, but exactly what restrictions the input has? Like, is it guaranteed to start with `/`? Does it always have more than 3 levels? Can it have an URL scheme? Etc.

Comment: In the input value there is no extensions. URL will be like /level1/level2/level3/level4/level5 and so on . The value I need is /level1/level2/level3 thats it. Thanks

Comment: Actually, `?matches(..., 'r')[0]` fits the work better than `?replace`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a solution using `?substring` and `?index_of`, however another solution would use `?split("/")`. This turns the string into a sequence that you may manipulate.

```
<#assign URL = "level1/level2/level3/level4/file" />

<#assign seqURL = URL?split('/') />

${seqURL[0]+'/'+seqURL[1]+'/'+seqURL[2]}
```

Another way to do this lookup, would be to chunk the sequence and join that first chunk.

```
${URL?split('/')?chunk(3)[0]?join("/")}
```

Comment: How would this work for an actual URL which includes a protocol, host and optionally a query string and hash?

Comment: @JasperdeVries 

You could split the URL string into sequences twice, narrowing down the substring to look at.  
  
    `<#assign URL = "http://www.URL.com/level1/level2/level3/level4/file" />`
    `${URL?split('.')[2]?keep_after('/')?split('/')?chunk(3)[0]?join("/")}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it always starts with `/`, you can do this with a regular expression:

```
${u?matches(r'^((/[^/]+){0,3})', 'r')[0]}
```

Note that this also works if there are less than 3 levels, or if the's exactly 3 levels but the 3rd doesn't end with `/`.

Answer (score 0):

By using freemarker builtin functions [index_of](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_index_of) , [substring](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_substring) and with a little help with [length](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_length)

```
${URL?substring(0, URL?index_of("level1/level2/level3") + 1 + "level1/level2/level3"?length}
```